# Slow mysql query with subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm experiencing a problem with this query in PHP. It is so slow I cannot connect to the server for few minutes after executing it. I've been removing separate subqueries away from main query and found out, that it works perfectly smooth, after I remove the last inner query.

Table "u" has 30.000 rows, table "u_r" around 17.000, table "u_s" around 13.000 and table "s" around 100. Even though tables "u_r" and "u_s" have lots of rows, only 2-3 rows have same "id_u" that matches the condition.

I hope, I provided enough information. If you need to know anything else, feel free to ask in the comments.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_p
FROM u
WHERE
    '$x' IN(
        SELECT id_p
        FROM u_p
        WHERE id_u=u.id_u
    )
    AND
    (
        '$y' IN (
            SELECT id_r
            FROM u_r
            WHERE id_u=u.id_u
        )
        OR
        '$y' IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT id_r
            FROM s
            WHERE id_s IN (
                SELECT id_s //without this query, everything works fine
                FROM u_s
                WHERE id_u=u.id_u
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Dont use IN, its slow. Use JOIN syntax as IN don't index results.

Comment: This is just a guess, but looks like you have nested sub queries, so that's bound to make things slower. That means for each row it's running the sub query for "$y" and then for each result of the sub query for "$y" it's running the sub-sub query. Maybe you should run explain on the query to see what's happening

Comment: I'm not clear on what your query is trying to do. But maybe you don't need all those sub queries and can use joins instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_r 
        FROM s 
        WHERE id_s IN ( 
            SELECT id_s //without this query, everything works fine 
                FROM u_s 
                WHERE id_u=u.id_u
```

to

```
SELECT s.id_s
        FROM u_s 
             INNER JOIN s ON u_s=id_u=u.id_u
        WHERE u_s.id_u = u.id_u
        GROUP BY s.id_r
```

Not tested as I'm trying to wrap my head around the structure.

Also remember to check the indexes. As a rough guide, you should have anything in the "WHERE" and anything in the "ON" indexed:

```
u_p.id_u
u_r.id_u
u_s.id_u
s.id_s
```

Answer (score 0):

Test that this produces the same results - should be much faster.

1. Replace the IN statements with inner joins. More opportunities for query optimiser to optimise this way
2. Eliminate your OR statement - I did this using a UNION. I think you could probably eliminate the OR using a LEFT JOIN instead if you wanted.
3. You'll need to test this - I don't have any sample data.

> ```
> select distinct id_p
> from u
> inner join u_p
> on u.id_u = u_p.id_u
> and u_p.id_u = '$x'
> inner join
> (
>   select id_r.id_u
>   from u_r
>   where id_r = '$y'   
>   union
>   select id_r
>   from s
>   inner join u_s
>   on s.id_u = u_s.id_u
>   where id_r = '$y'
> ) as subq
> on u.id_u = subq.id_u
> ```